# List of abbreviations in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, lists, acronyms

I created list of abbreviations in my thesis using following after `\begin{document}. It created the List of Abbreviations correct, but it appear in table content in wrong order. I want the List of Abbreviations to come before the list of appendix tables. I am using a this template 
[enter link description here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/thesis-template-for-north-dakota-state-university-ndsu/jssgnvzcctfy). Would anyone help me please?

```
 \frontmatter
    \setcounter{page}{12}   
        \heading{List of Abbreviations}
        \noindent 
        AMPA\dotfill Aminomethylphosphonic Acid\\
        \mainmatter
```

[image]

Here is my MMW

```
    \documentclass[ms-thesis]{ndsu-thesis}


\abstract{This is the abstract for my thesis.}
\acknowledgements{I acknowledge people here.}
\dedication{This thesis is dedicated to my cat, Mr. Fluffles.}
\preface{You can put a preface here.}

    \begin{document}
        \frontmatter
        \setcounter{page}{12}   
        \heading{List of Abbreviations}
        \noindent 
        AMPA\dotfill Aminomethylphosphonic Acid\\
        \mainmatter

    \heading{The First Chapter}
    \section{Introduction}
    This is a section of my thesis.

    \heading{The Second Chapter}
    \section{Excellent results}
    This is another section of my thesis.
    \subsection{Minor results}
    This is a subsection of my thesis.

    \begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \caption{Table captions go at the top of the table}
    \begin{tabular}{rl}
    Number & Month \\
    \hline
    1 & January \\
    2 & February \\
    3 & March
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}


    \bibliographystyle{plain}
    \bibliography{my-bib-file}

    \appendix
    I can include appendix material here. See Figure \ref{figure_a} below.

    \begin{appendixfigure}
    \centering
    You could include a figure here.
    \caption{Figure captions go at the bottom of the figure}
    \label{figure_a}
    \end{appendixfigure}

    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Use `preto` from `etoolbox` package to add your code right before `\listofappendixtables` is entered.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
    \preto{\listofappendixtables}{
            \heading{List of Abbreviations}
            \noindent 
            AMPA\dotfill Aminomethylphosphonic Acid\\
                        }
```

Full code

```
%% Please see http://texdoc.net/pkg/ndsu-thesis for full documentation and options

%% phd,ms-thesis,ms-paper,ma-thesis,ma-paper
\documentclass[ms-thesis]{ndsu-thesis}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\title{The Title of My M.S. Thesis}
\author{Samuel Quincy Student}
\date{April 2016}
\department{Mathematics}
\cchair{Prof. John Adams}
\cmembera{Prof. Abraham Lincoln}
\cmemberb{Prof. George Washington}
\approvaldate{15 April 2016}
\approver{Prof. James Garfield}
\abstract{This is the abstract for my thesis.}
\acknowledgements{I acknowledge people here.}
\dedication{This thesis is dedicated to my cat, Mr. Fluffles.}
\preface{You can put a preface here.}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
    \preto{\listofappendixtables}{
            \heading{List of Abbreviations}
            \noindent 
            AMPA\dotfill Aminomethylphosphonic Acid\\
                        }

\begin{document}

%% DO NOT USE \maketitle!!!

%% DO NOT USE \chapter!!!
\heading{The First Chapter}

This is the first chapter. Use \textit{blank lines} between paragraphs; never use \texttt{\\} to create new `paragraphs'!

This is a second paragraph.

\section{Introduction}
This is a section of my thesis.


\heading{The Second Chapter}

\section{Excellent results}
This is another section of my thesis.
\subsection{Minor results}
This is a subsection of my thesis.
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Table captions go at the top of the table}
\begin{tabular}{rl}
Number & Month \\
\hline
1 & January \\
2 & February \\
3 & March
4
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

%% Uncomment these lines for a bibliography. Remember to upload your .bib file and update the file name here accordingly!
% \bibliographystyle{plain}
% \bibliography{my-bib-file}


\appendix  %% For unnamed appendix
% \namedappendix{Appendix title}  %% For named appendix
Note that this class does not support the use of multiple appendices.

I can include appendix material here. See Figure \ref{figure_a} below. Use \texttt{appendixfigure} or \texttt{appdixtable} in the Appendix.

\begin{appendixfigure}
\centering
You could include a figure here.
\caption{Figure captions go at the bottom of the figure}
\label{figure_a}
\end{appendixfigure}

\begin{appendixtable}
\centering
You could include a table here.
\caption{Table captions go at the bottom of the figure}
\label{table:a}
\end{appendixtable}

\end{document}
```

**NOTE:** You should not set the page number manually in tables of contents or lists. LaTeX automatically detects the page number and place it there for you.

Comment: Thanks @Al-Motasem! but I need the list of abbreviations before the list of appendix table only not the list of table.

Comment: @user192739. Corrected.

Comment: Thank you @Al-Motasem

Comment: Do you know how to set the space between each abbreviations to be doublespace  ?@Al-Motasem

Comment: @user192739 Use `\renewcommand{\newline}{\\[\baselineskip]}` right after `\heading{List of Abbreviations}` then start the list of abbreviations entries and use `\newline` to finish each entry.